# iOS BLE scanning when screen is on

Tags: ios, bluetooth, push-notification, bluetooth-lowenergy, ibeacon

We are developing a BLE application using iBeacons on iOS. We want to **display a notification** when the user is within the iBeacon region as fast as possible (ideally **within 2seconds** when he reachs the region).

Two questions:

1. Is the Region Monitoring API always called when the user clic on the home button and screen turns on ?
2. If the user is already using the mobile phone (screen is on), the BLE app is not running at all even in background and he approches the beacon: is there a way to force the Region Monitoring API to be called? Because now, we need to wait several minutes in order to get a notification.

Thanks a lot for your kind help !
David

Answer (score 0):

You can turn on Background Mode for your app. Check UIBackgroundModes in apple docs. There are Bluetooth LE accessories Modes that can handle the background scanning and checking of iBeacons(Even when the screen is off).

You can check the background modes documentation at https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html

Comment: @jiama I edited my post to clarify my questions. I want to know if the region monitoring is always performed when the user wakes up his smartphone (=screen off) by pressing the home button.

Answer (score 0):

CLLocationManager has a method below:

```
open func startRangingBeacons(in region: CLBeaconRegion)
```